# Stack Overflow API: get the user's "new mail!" notification?

Tags: web-applications, stackexchange-api

When someone replies to your question (or for many other actions on the site) you get a little "new mail!" type icon in your "StackExchange" menu in the top left of the site.

Checking out the API docs here:
http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/usage

I don't see a way to get that "new mail" count for the logged in user. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is currently not possible to access this information using the stackoverflow API v1.1. However, the draft changes for the [stackoverflow API v2.0](https://stackapps.com/questions/2588/draft-specification-for-api-v2-0) does contain what you are looking for and is worth keeping an eye on.

> **Inbox Access**
>
> A new route, /users/{ids}/inbox, will return items in
>   inboxes.  It will be just enough information for  display purposes, a
>   la stackexchange.com’s inbox tab. This method will require an auth
>   code with `read_inbox` permissions granted.

Comment: Thank you, looking forward to API v2.0.

Comment: who give you the +50 bounties ?